# How to get a wind effect afecting multiple meshes in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a very tall, and thin, tower of cubes one on top of the other, each with a rigidbody attached.
I'm trying to build it higher and higher and have a wind blowing at random heights to try to blow it up and demolish it. It seems simple, but I can't do it properly.

I need to do something as the wind zones for tree, and I cannot attach the forces to the cubes since I need something to instantiate randomly at certain times or places that "pushes" the cubes to make them fall.

I've tried with a particle system, but I was unable to make the particles as collider objects (is this even possible?).

Any suggestion?

Comment: You're on the right track with forces I'd say. Perhaps attach the forces at run time?

Answer (score 0):

[Interactive cloth](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-InteractiveCloth.html) might be your choice.

[image]

To add an Interactive Cloth in the scene, click menu

- GameObject -> Create Other -> Cloth.
- Add new anchor GameObjects (Menu GameObject > Create Empty Object)
- For each game object, add a collider component (Menu Component >
  Physics > Box Collider)
- For each collider, specify the center and size of the collider
- For each collider, specify the 3D location of collider, at which the
  cloth remains static
- Make sure the collider overlaps/intersects with the cloth, otherwise, it won’t work.

For your case, if you wish to programmatically specify the anchor position (since it is random), you might wish to refer to [this tutorial](http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/unity-3d-add-automatic-anchors-for-interactive-cloth/#more-2465) as well.